# ng-Select drop down disable and disable or remove close button

Tags: angular, dropdown, html-select, angular-ngselect

I used ng-select option menu but i want to disable or remove it's close button how to do this. here i used code `

```
<ng-select id="CompanyID"  [(ngModel)]="CompanyId" placeholder="-- select an option --">
 <ng-option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </ng-option>
 <ng-option *ngFor="let company of Company" [value]="company.Company_ID" [disabled]="true">{{company.Name}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>`
```

Comment: Don't combine reactive form and template form together. Use any one of them

Comment: I removed FormController but it's not work

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/132

Answer (score 10):

Best way is to use `[clearable]="false"` so that you don't have to use css.

```
<ng-select [clearable]="false">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 3):

How I would do is, create a CSS class called no-clear -

```
.no-clear.ng-select .ng-clear-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

Then use that class in your ng-select template,

```
<ng-select class="no-clear"
           [items]="youtData"
           [(ngModel)]="yourModel">
</ng-select>
```

Or you can also use `[clearable]="false"` directive.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ng-select [clearable]="false">
</ng-select>
```

Just add the attribute `[clearable]="false"`